# Django : Error thrown by database : relation "_mytable" does not exist (for a content_type) . Lost app-name

Tags: sql, django, django-models

In Django, I have a model, let's call it "MyTable" which uses a content_type Foreign Key to refer to, amongst other things, Profile.

In most cases (as in my unit-tests) I have no trouble with it, but in a certain circumstance in the view I try to save a Profile object (with Profile's .save() ) and the database throws this exception :

```
relation "_mytable" does not  exist
```

I presume that this is because of some reverse-lookup that the ORM is making between the Profile and MyTable due to the ForeignKey from MyTable to Profile.

Now there definitely is a relation in the database called myapp_mytable. But in this case, the ORM seems to have lost the app-name. Checking the SQL confirms this, it really is trying to select from _mytable instead of myapp_mytable.

Anyone seen anything like this or have suggestions?

Comment: First thought is that your import order is probably weird. Are you importing the model before your settings.py file?

Comment: that's an interesting thought ... let me check

Comment: yes ... the ordering *is* weird. Will keep investigating in that direction, cheers

Comment: maybe not ... seem to have fixed ordering, but problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you resolved or worked around this by now, but I ran across the same.

My case sounds a little different than yours, but it took me several hours to figure out so I'll post the issue here for reference.

In my case, I had code in my **model** that was expecting data to be pre-loaded in the database and it wasn't.

The query appeared to work fine when run from shell, however, when I ran the same code in the unittest it would fail with the "relation not found" error.

The reason was that, when run from shell the data I was expecting was *already* loaded in my DB.  However, in the testcase situation (the "manage.py test" behavior is to create an empty db before test) , while I *was* defining the testcase's fixture, the fixture is not loaded prior to model validation/evaluation.  So the expected fixture data didn't exist when I was expecting it.

Comment: thanks ... I don't remember if I got to the bottom of this problem but it vanished at some point. I'll look out for this if something similar happens.